# Let $n_1e, n_2e,\ldots,n_ke$ be k numbers, find $e$ if $n_i\in\mathbb{Z}^+$

Tags: algorithms, discrete-optimization

I have measured a quantized (or discrete) physical quantity. This means that there exists a fundamental quantity $e$ such that the physical quantity is an integer $n$ times the fundamental quantity $e$. For example, if I measure $1,3,2,4$ then $e$ is $1$. The quantities measured are fixed positive real numbers and they will be of the form $n_1e, n_2e,\ldots,n_ke$. What is an efficient algorithm for finding $e$? This is equivalent to finding the set of positive integer numbers $n_1,\ldots,n_k$.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: The Euclidean algorithm could be of use here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm.

Comment: Is it possible that $e=1/2$ in your example? If not, I think you must already know something about the fundamental quantity before you even take the first measurement. In practice, however, if you take a large number of measurements, the chance that they would _all_ come out to an even multiple of the fundamental quantity seems small. That's how Millikan justified the measurement of the charge of the electron, IIRC.

Comment: @DavidK $e$ is equivalent to the fundamental charge of electron, and it is approximately $1.6\times 10^{-19}$. My fundamental quantity is indeed the greatest common divisor.

Comment: The problem may be difficult. If one imagines hat the measurements of the $n_ie$ are *exact*, the (slightly generalized) gcd does the job. But real measurements will have errors.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Indeed one has to combine the gcd method with the uncertainties.

Comment: @VladimirVargas What I'm trying to say is that if you only look at four oil drops, each bearing some number of excess electrons, it is possible (seemingly not even _too_ unlikely) that you would have chosen four oil drops that bore respectively 2, 6, 4, and 8 electrons. If even and odd charges are equally likely, then there is a $1/16$ chance that all four oil drops would have an even charge. So it's a matter of finding the GCD _and_ establishing that there are enough observations to rule out the possibility that the GCD is a multiple of $e$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Probably the way to go is, if I have two physical measurements $A\pm a, B\pm b$, then I will perform the gcd method and I stop when the remainder includes $0$ in its uncertainty range.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, I will indeed measure many many times.

Comment: @VladimirVargas Yes, I thought you would. I should have said I do not question your method, but just wanted it to be clear to someone else who might read this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely,
$$e=\gcd(n_1e,\dots,n_ke)$$
where $\gcd$ is the greatest common divisor function.
Actually, the right hand side is
$$\gcd(n_1e,\dots,n_ke)=e\cdot\gcd(n_1,\dots,n_k),$$
where $\gcd(n_1,\dots,n_k)$ is *likely* equal to one.
This function can be calculated recursively for $k>2$.
If $$g_i=\gcd(n_1,\dots,n_i)$$ for $1\le i\le k$, then
$g_{i+1}=\gcd(g_i,n_{i+1})$. GCDs of two arguments can be found using the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), which successively replaces one of the two arguments, discarding their signs, by its remainder modulo the other, terminating with the last nonzero remainder.

Also, it is interesting to note that the probability of two random integers [being coprime](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Probability/TwoCoprime.shtml) (having $\gcd=1$) is $\frac6{\pi^2}$, so the probability of $k$ random integers all being pairwise coprime would be
$$1-\left(1-\frac6{\pi^2}\right)^k.$$
But this probably won't apply to your observations unless the $n_i$ are all far from unity. For $n_i$ close to $1$, one would need to know their distribution to estimate this likelihood.